# Why does sed replace my quote marks?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a SQL query which contains:

```
join (&max_dt1) t3
```

I want to replace `&max_dt1` so:

```
MAX_DT1="'2017-11-03'"
REPLACE="sed -i 's/&max_dt1/select ($MAX_DT1) as dt/g' $FINAL_QUERY"
cat $FINAL_QUERY | eval $REPLACE
```

Result:

```
join (select (2017-05-09) as dt) t3
```

Why is it deleting the quote marks of my variable `MAX_DT1`?

My real code:

```
MAX_DT1="'$MAX_DT1'"
echo $MAX_DT1
REPLACE="sed -i 's/&max_dt1/select ($MAX_DT1) as dt/g' $FINAL_QUERY"
echo sed -i "s/&max_dt1/select ($MAX_DT1) as dt/g $FINAL_QUERY
cat $FINAL_QUERY | eval $REPLACE
```

MAX_DT1 first of all contains just: 2017-11-03

Comment: What quote marks?  echo $MAX_DT1 and check the output.

Comment: Oh, or is the question why it's `2017-05-09` instead of `'2017-05-09'`?

Comment: shouldn't it be `2017-11-03`, why is the date changing?

Comment: Sorry I just copied bad, my original code it's MAX_DT1="'$MAX_DT1'" I've already had double quotes

Comment: Can you edit your code with clear information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes indicates that you affect a string to MAX_DT1 variable. It's not part of your string.
If your variable value has to contains quotes then you have to add them.
For instance:

```
MAX_DT1="'2017-11-03'"
```

Unfortunately your Next REPLACE variable won't have what you're expecting and the eval command called later won't work since its sed command would be bad formatted (if you keep your code this way).

Fortunately, your problem is solved if you call directly the sed command this way:

```
MAX_DT1="'2017-11-03'"
sed -i "s/&max_dt1/select ($MAX_DT1) as dt/g" $FINAL_QUERY
```

Answer (score 2):

follow this

```
$ query="join (&max_dt1) t3"
$ MAX_DT1="'2017-11-03'"   # <--- you have to quote the single quotes!!
$ sed "s/&max_dt1/select ($MAX_DT1) as dt/g" <<< $query

join (select ('2017-11-03') as dt) t3
```

Comment: note that double quotes wrapping the single quotes!

Comment: your evaluation is not clean, you have already quoted `sed` script with single quotes, same type of quotes cannot be nested without escaping.  Just follow my example.

Comment: Why are you using double quote for sed? This is not gonna work

Comment: it works and will work, otherwise `bash` cannot substitute values and you need to do quote dance around variables you want bash to expand..